# how to change documents in greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, greasemonkey

I am new to greasemonkey and I wondering If I Can I do something like this in greasemonkey ?

1. Script gets triggered
2. Finds few urls from the current document
3. Serially load each found url as new document to work with and extract new info from them.

Something like this

```
for(i=1;i<20;i++){
set current doc to a[i]
exract something from current doc
}
```

Any info on this highly appreciated.

Comment: If the pages are static, just use `GM_xmlhttpRequest` to get their static data.  If the pages are dynamic, you can redirect to the new page (killing the current script instance) or load the new page in a new tab or iframe. **Provide more details** of what you are really trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Brock. What I want to accomplish here is to find some n number of urls in docx and open each of the url in tab or window and generate mouse click event on a specific element I find on the opened url. how do you think I can accomplish this ?